# Redimensionar componentes ao aumentar janela

Tags: c++, qt

Como posso redimensionar os componentes dentro do `QWidget` quando aumentar a janela?

Exemplo, de como fica:

[image: exemplo]

Comment: Você está criando a janela e os componentes via código ou usando o editor de janelas do Qt? Está definindo um layout para a janela?

Comment: Criando no editor de janela. Quando abre fica normal, Mas quando tenta aumenta, todos os objetos fica fixo.

Comment: Tem certeza que definiu o layout da janela, em vez de apenas criar um layout dentro da janela?

Comment: Aprenda a usar _Layouts_, veja este vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Ud6FonsR4

Comment: Aee. foi só seleciona o `Lay Out`. Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solução: layouts

Você pode utilizar **[layouts](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layouts-basiclayouts.html)** em vez de colocar os componentes diretamente no widget em posições pré-determinadas por coordenadas fixas.

Sua interface fica muito mais consistente, se tornando independente dos tamanhos das fontes ou estilo visual do sistema em questão, além de proporcionar um melhor aproveitamento da tela quando a UI é bem construída.

### Usando Qt Designer

Se estiver usando o Qt Designer basta colocar os controles na posição aproximada no widget desejado, selecionar o widget e aplicar um layout, nos botões destacados a seguir, ou inserir um layout diretamente no widget pegando da lista à esquerda, e depois adicionar controles nos lugares desejados.

[image: Captura de tela do Qt Designer com ítens destacados]

Aproveite e veja também a documentação do `QLayout`, em especial os `QVBoxLayout`, `QHBoxLayout`, `QGridLayout` e `QFormLayout`, que cobrem os casos mais comuns de uso.

### Usando layouts diretamente no código-fonte

[image: Exemplo de layouts aninhados]

Código-fonte:

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Dialog();

private:
    void createMenu();
    void createHorizontalGroupBox();
    void createGridGroupBox();
    void createFormGroupBox();

    enum { NumGridRows = 3, NumButtons = 4 };

    QMenuBar *menuBar;
    QGroupBox *horizontalGroupBox;
    QGroupBox *gridGroupBox;
    QGroupBox *formGroupBox;
    QTextEdit *smallEditor;
    QTextEdit *bigEditor;
    QLabel *labels[NumGridRows];
    QLineEdit *lineEdits[NumGridRows];
    QPushButton *buttons[NumButtons];
    QDialogButtonBox *buttonBox;

    QMenu *fileMenu;
    QAction *exitAction;
};

Dialog::Dialog()
{
    createMenu();
    createHorizontalGroupBox();
    createGridGroupBox();
    createFormGroupBox();

    buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok
                                     | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);

    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

    mainLayout->setMenuBar(menuBar);

    mainLayout->addWidget(horizontalGroupBox);
    mainLayout->addWidget(gridGroupBox);
    mainLayout->addWidget(formGroupBox);
    mainLayout->addWidget(bigEditor);
    mainLayout->addWidget(buttonBox);

    setLayout(mainLayout);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Basic Layouts"));
}

void Dialog::createGridGroupBox()
{
    gridGroupBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Grid layout"));

    for (int i = 0; i < NumGridRows; ++i) {
        labels[i] = new QLabel(tr("Line %1:").arg(i + 1));
        lineEdits[i] = new QLineEdit;
        layout->addWidget(labels[i], i + 1, 0);
        layout->addWidget(lineEdits[i], i + 1, 1);
    }

    smallEditor = new QTextEdit;
    smallEditor->setPlainText(tr("This widget takes up about two thirds of the "
                                "grid layout."));
    layout->addWidget(smallEditor, 0, 2, 4, 1);

    layout->setColumnStretch(1, 10);
    layout->setColumnStretch(2, 20);
    gridGroupBox->setLayout(layout);
}

void Dialog::createFormGroupBox()
{
    formGroupBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Form layout"));
    QFormLayout *layout = new QFormLayout;
    layout->addRow(new QLabel(tr("Line 1:")), new QLineEdit);
    layout->addRow(new QLabel(tr("Line 2, long text:")), new QComboBox);
    layout->addRow(new QLabel(tr("Line 3:")), new QSpinBox);
    formGroupBox->setLayout(layout);
}
```

<sub>Veja este código com maiores explicações na [documentação da Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layouts-basiclayouts.html)</sub>

> Lembre-se de que, tanto no Qt Designer quanto via código-fonte, você pode aninhar layouts como no exemplo acima, para ter um maior controle sobre a interface.